# Почему iPad подменяет .png на .jpeg?

Tags: php

1. Я сохраняю .png картинку в iPad (iOS 7.1.1)
2. Я загружаю эту картинку из iPad в свой скрипт, но $_FILES['userfile']['type'] почему-то показывает - image/jpeg
3. Если я загружаю картинку на Яндекс.Диск, приложение правильно определяет что это .png

Вопросы:

1. Почему так происходит? С компьютера и с телефона - загружается с правильным типом.
2. Как правильно определить mime тип загружаемого файла? Как это удаётся Яндекс.Диску?

Примечание:

Функция getimagesize тоже показывает что загружаемый файл - image/jpeg

UPD:

Я заметила что качество изображения ухудшается. Думаю, при сохранении iPad сохраняет и оригинал и сжатый .jpg (чтобы показывать на своём экране). Наверное, приложение Яндекс.Диск просто имеет доступ к оригиналам изображений, а вот через форму загрузки файлов в браузере отправляются сжатые .jpg копии.

Если всё так, тогда вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы пользователи сайта могли загружать оригинальные изображения со своих айпадов, а не ухудшенные копии?

Comment: Может где-то происходит конвертирование? На диск через приложение?

Comment: @VadimPedchenko Не поняла второй вопрос )) На Яндекс.Диск я загружаю через приложение на айпаде. А сохраняю картинку через браузер на айпаде ) Я бы предположила, что айпад все сохраняемые картинки преобразует в JPG, но тогда бы Яндекс.Диск распознавал их тоже как JPG, а он правильно определяет. А мой скрипт в браузере на айпаде - неправильно. Мистика какая-то )))

Comment: Причем тут айпод,айпад, когда загрузка происходит на сервер? Одно дело, когда картинка имеет формат `jpg` но переименовали ее в `png`. - Но вы же грузите на свой сервер, где у вас есть специальный скрипт (который вы не показали). - И лучше проверять правильность изображений с помощью `getimagesize` или через `exif_imagetype `. А вообще, покажите примерный кусок кода, который вы пишете на сервере, для загрузки.

Comment: @And я показала скрипт ) В нём нет ничего лишнего, только выводится $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] или печатается getimagesize. И так и эдак - тип .jpg. Загрузить пытаюсь настоящий .png, созданный как .png - и другие устройства загружают его как положено. Только iPad как .jpg - значит, он всё-таки в галерею сохраняет сжатые .jpg

Comment: Скприпта нет, помощи нет, одни догадки. И все равно я не понимаю, причем тут айпад. Возможно у вас при сохранении `jpg` - функция которая автоматом все картинки делает `jpg`. Без кода ничего не скажешь тут. К сожалению

Comment: @And честно, я не понимаю какой ещё код вы хотите увидеть? HTML форму что-ли? Самая обычная для загрузки картинок. Или PHP? Ну ладно, вот - <? echo $_FILES['pornokartinka']['type']; ?> Это весь скрипт.

Comment: Тогда явно у вас вообще ничего загружаться не будет. Ибо вы не используете скрипт загрузки, его нет.

Comment: @And вы, случайно, не путаете загрузку файла с загрузкой файла и его сохранением? Когда я файл сохраняю - я уж точно знаю что сохраняю, и потом с форматами всё отлично. Я понимаю, что сложно в это поверить, но мой айпад сохраняет .png в .jpg ) Тут, конечно, вопросы к iOS. Может быть в новых версиях Apple перестали вмешиваться в форматы и качество сохраняемых файлов. ))

Comment: Скорей, всего - это вы, вообще не понимаете, что делаете и как работает загрузка.

Comment: @And что, по-вашему, происходит, когда в форме отправки файла выбран файл и нажата кнопка отправить? Файл не загружается на сервер? Просто происходит какая-то магия? ))

Comment: Почитайте стандарты `RFC-1867`. И как именно `сервер (в нашем случае php)` получает файл от браузера и что нужно делать дальше, чтобы файл, действительно загрузился.

Comment: @And формы и моего кода недостаточно для того чтобы получить данные о файле из массива $FILES? К временному файлу нельзя применять getimagesize?

Comment: Во первых не `$FILES`, а `$_FILES`, а во вторых -это лишь временный файл. В третьих `getimagesize` не просматривает весь файл. а берет лишь заголовки, а что если я их подменю или еще лучше - напишу в конец файла шел? Тогда вашему серверу, будет плохо.

Comment: @And во-первых, это опечатка ) Во-вторых, так я же ничего не подменяю и могу доверять заголовкам? Картинка .png, но с айпада определяется как .jpg ) Похоже, вы уже забыли с чего всё началось )) Я предоставила достаточный код, а вы утверждали, что этого мало.

Comment: Я не увидел не одной функции `image*` и сохранение именно картинки, а не любого файла, при-этом видимо у вас статично стоит формат `jpg`, а картинка никак не сохраняется и при выводе `jpg`, а надо выводить формат загруженной картинки.

Comment: @And спасибо большое за ответы ) Но я всё равно не понимаю - что значит - статично стоит формат jpg? Где стоит? Куда смотреть? Картинку png я делаю сама в фотошопе, потом загружаю на сервер по FTP, потом открываю в браузере по ссылке и сохраняю на устройства. В компьютер, в телефон и в iPad. Потом через форму выбираю её и оправляю своему скрипту. С ПК показывает тип - png, с телефона показывает тип - png, а с айпада показывает тип - jpg. Как это можно объяснить?

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не доверяйте на 100% `$_FILES['upfile']['mime']` всегда используйте fileinfo, это мне помогло.

**Core PHP(http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php):**

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

$checkMimeFile = array_search(
    $finfo->file(
        $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']
    ),
    [
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'png' => 'image/png',
    ],
    true
)

if (false === $checkMimeFile) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
}
```

Comment: Почему не доверять? Как отличаются алгоритмы получения mime type?

Comment: Потому что вы увидели это на php.net в комментарии которому 4 года?

Comment: @VadimPedchenko, потому что нельзя доверять, ибо я могу подменить `HTTP-заголовки` на любой другой `Content-Type: image/jpeg` - тут что угодно можно написать. Простой проверкой через тип не удастся убедиться, что это правильная картинка, без шелов. - Ко всему сведению, что метод `getimagesize`, и другие, берут только заголовки, весь файл не просматривается. Для более  верного решения, нужно пересохранять картинки через `GD`, чтобы убрать ненужные заголовки и другие данные, которые не являются частью картинки.